# form should not submit on enter if focus is not on submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I have a requirement where user cannot submit the form if he press enter key unless focus will be on submit button.

Using following code, I am able to do that, but now the issue is, if I have any enter key event attached specific to any field (e.g. if I want to attach enter key event to one textfield for some special requirement), it is not allowing me due to the script I have written below..

```
<script>
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    var $focusedItem = $(document.activeElement);
    if($focusedItem.is("button") || $focusedItem.is("a") || $focusedItem.attr("type") == "submit") {
        $focusedItem.click();
    } 
    else {
            event.preventDefault();
         }
    }
});
</script>
```

Any solution where I can restrict user from submitting form on pressing enter key, if focus is not on the submit button but at the same time if there will be any enter key event attached to any form-field, that should also work.

Answer (score 0):

If you had created a JsFiddle it would be easier to help.  However, I'm thinking you should do something like this:

```
if($focusedItem.attr('id') == 'submitButton') {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        submit the form
    }
}else if ($focusedItem.attr('id') == 'Anothertextarea') {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        do something special
    }
}else{
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.This is a global requirement throughout one corporate web application. But this will block all the enter key events, I dont want to block if say I have some special enter key event on a textbox which populates some results on enter.

Comment: Edited my response.  You can use elseif statements to configure multiple scenarios for this keycode press.

Comment: I want to write a generic javascript to restrict user from submitting form on enter. The application contains number of pages, forms, enter key events on number of form fields..

Answer (score 0):

Try that and see if it fits your needs:

### --DEMO--

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).on('click', ':submit', function (e) {
    if (!$(document.activeElement).is(':submit')) return;
    var form = $(this).closest('form').length ? $(this).closest('form')[0] : $('#' + $(this).attr('form'))[0];
    form.submit();
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not helping me as it doesn't have any key event script.

Comment: You should provide a jsFiddle which replicates your issue, i'm not sure to understand what you are looking for

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YAY6w/  This is the jsFiddle example with expected solution (for should submit only when focus is on submit button, but it should not block if there is any enter key events on any of the field like textbox in this case) .. The form is getting submitted only pressing enter key only if focus is on submit button but at the same time if enter key is pressed when focus is on textbox, it doesn't block the enter key event present on that textbox.

Comment: @ajay Not sure what you are looking for, but that's your jsFiddle fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/YAY6w/1/

Comment: whenever I was using preventDefault for preventing form to submit if focus is not on submit button, it was preventing the other enter key events on the other fields.. I used jQuery "bind" and it worked

Comment: @Wolff Lol.. you have edited my jsFiddle fixed without any change and pasted the URL...

Comment: @ajay Well not really, i unwrapped your code from onload function to fix error regarding `Uncaught ReferenceError: checkEnterKey is not defined `. Anyway, i don't really see what you are talking about. If you have fixed your issue, then consider to post an answer and close this question, regards...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line event.stopPropagation(); from your script, you need only the preventDefault() (prevents the submit).

When you do stopPropagation() you are stopping all other keypress events on the element.

Comment: Yes, I have removed stopPropogation();
But restricting enter key event throughout the document and allowing it to working only when focus is on submit, is causing the issue that if I have any such event on any textbox/textarea, that is also getting blocked.
Any solution

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing the point, this is basically a standard html issue.

Don't give the form an submit action (move it to a click event directly on the button) and change all button types to button instead of submit.

I can't remember if simply removing the submit from the form is enough.  If not then just do onSubmit="return false;"   I think that does it.

However as a note the requirement for this as a global behavior is probably wrong and if its for the government then you will probably get in trouble since its not compliant with accessibility guidelines.