# keyup event is not triggered with "enter" key

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to prevent postback that occurs when input field is focused and `Enter` key is clicked.
The problem is that when I am debugging this code:

```
$fields.each(function(){                                     
    var fieldName = $(this).attr("id");

    try {
        console.log(fieldName);
    }
    catch (e) { }

    $(this).after("<div class='additionalFieldInfo'></div>");
    $(this).after("<input type='text' placeholder='Type here to search' 
        class='specialDataField' id='temp_" + fieldName + "' size=80>");

    $(this).hide();
    $("#temp_"+fieldName).keyup(function(key){
    debugger;
...
```

the `enter` key is causing a postback and not triggering the event (the line with `debugger` does not hit). All other keys are do trigger the `keyup` event, so they are actually triggering, just not for the `enter` key.

Comment: Block the form's POST rather than fiddle about with catching keys: `$(document).on("submit", "form", function() { return false; })`

Comment: @freedomn-m How would you submit the form then? OP just wants the enter key to **not** submit the form

Comment: you have to `return false` or `preventDefault` in the submit event handler.

Comment: Note that `this` is a reference to the element already, so using that to build a jQuery object to get the `id` to then build another jQuery object is entirely redundant. Similarly for the `try`/`catch` block around `console.log`.

Comment: if you have submit button on form,Hitting Enter key will submit the form.

Comment: @A.Wolff Without further information, it *looks like* OP is using an ajax request on the form and the POST is interfering with that.  Otherwise, removing enter = POST while button click still = POST is just bad UX.

Comment: @freedomn-m Ya it could be just that, not sure. Anyway, maybe OP looks for something like that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23502075/1414562

Comment: i want to "catch" the `keyup` event, when enter key is entering on keyboard, and do something else then postback